# Java defining or initializing attributes of a class

Tags: java, class, attributes, initializing

Is there a difference between *defining* class attributes and *initializing* them? Are there cases where you want to do one over the other?

**Example:**

The following code snippets should point out the difference that I mean. I'm using a primitive and an object there:

```
import Java.util.Random;

public class Something extends Activity {
    int integer;
    Random random = null;

    Something(){
        integer = 0;
        random = new Random();
        ....
```

vs.

```
import Java.util.Random;

public class Something extends Activity {
    int integer = null;
    Random random;

    Something(){
        integer = 0;
        random = new Random();
        ....
```

Comment: I would list the variables at the class level and initialize them with a constructor.

Comment: also you're trying to pass a null to a primitive which could cause some headaches.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Firstly you cannot set a primitive to be null as a primitive is just data where `null` is an object reference. If you tried to compile `int i = null` you would get a incompatible types error.

Secondly initializing the variables to `null` or `0` when declaring them in the class is redundant as in Java, primitives default to `0` (or `false`) and object references default to `null`. This is not the case for local variables however, if you tried the below you would get an initialization error at compile time

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     int i;
     System.out.print(i);
 }
```

Explicitly initializing them to a default value of `0` or `false` or `null` is pointless but you might want to set them to another default value then you can create a constructor that has the default values for example

```
public MyClass
{
   int theDate = 9;
   String day = "Tuesday";

   // This would return the default values of the class
   public MyClass()
   {
   }

   // Where as this would return the new String
   public MyClass (String aDiffDay)
   {
      day = aDiffDay;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shanku and Morpheus answered the question correctly. First, you will get a compile error setting your primitive int variable "integer" to null; you can only do that for Objects. Second, Shanku is right that Java assigns default values to **instance variables**, which are "integer" and "random" in your example code; instance variables are viewable within the class or beyond depending on the scope (public, private, protected, package).

However, default values are **not** assigned for **local variables**. For instance, if you assigned a variable in your constructor like "int height;" then it will not be initialized to zero.

I would recommend reading the [Java variable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), which describe the variables very well and furthermore you could also look over the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/certification/javase-7-programmer1.html), which again are great reading material.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, initializing is defined explicitly in the language specification. For fields and array components, when items are created, they are automatically set to the following default values by the system:

numbers: 0 or 0.0

booleans: false

object references: null

This means that explicitly setting fields to 0, false, or null (as the case may be) is unnecessary and redundant.