# Please Help Trying to sort array Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
  public class selectionsorter
  {
public selectionsorter(int[] x)
{
    theArray=x;
}
public void sort()
{
    for(int i=0; i<theArray.length-1;i++)
    {
        start=i;
        findMinPos();
    }
}
public void findMinPos()
{
    int minpos=start;
    for(int i=0;i<theArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(i>start)
        {
        if(theArray[i]<theArray[start])
        {
        start=i;
        }
        }
    }
    swap();
}
public void swap()
{
    temp=theArray[start];
    theArray[start]=theArray[minpos];
    theArray[minpos]=temp;
}
private int[] theArray;
private int minpos;
private int start;
private int temp;
   }
```

Tester File

```
   public class selectionsortertester
  {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] x ={3,7,5,6,9,2};
    selectionsorter y=new selectionsorter(x);

    y.sort();
    for(int i=0; i<x.length;i++)
    System.out.print(x[i]+" ");
}
  }
```

I want it to sort the array it from lowest to highest and it does the first number, and the output is "2 7 5 6 9 3" Please Help and Thanks
Does anyone know why it is doing this and how I can fix it, Thanks

Comment: You should use [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), Class names should start with Upper case

Comment: Welcome to SO. If any of the answers help you succesfully resolves your issue, [please accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
Arrays.sort(x);
```

See docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29).

Comment: After `int[] x ={3,7,5,6,9,2};` in your main code. And you don't need `selectionsorter` at all.

Comment: it still isn't working correctly, I want it to output the array from lowest to highest, but I just swaps the first number

Comment: Remove this code: `selectionsorter y=new selectionsorter(x); y.sort();`

Comment: You should add `import java.util.Arrays;` in the beginning of file after `package`. But I can't believe that you do it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally got it. In the class file in the findMinPos method I declared minpos

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you kept all the variables as [Class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479038/what-is-attribute-in-java) instead of local variables in the methods, and all your methods are changing the class variables.

This is incorrect.
Remove these from the class

```
private int minpos;
private int start;
private int temp;
```

Now pass the values as method arguments:

```
public class SelectionSorter {
    public SelectionSorter(int[] x) {
        theArray = x;
    }

    public void sort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length - 1; i++) {
            findMinPos(i);
        }
    }

    public void findMinPos(int start) {
        int minpos = start;
        for (int i = start + 1; i < theArray.length; i++) {
            if (theArray[i] < theArray[start]) {
                minpos = i;
            }
        }
        if (minpos != start) {
            swap(minpos,start);
        }
    }

    public void swap(int minpos, int start) {
        int temp = theArray[minpos];
        theArray[minpos] = theArray[start];
        theArray[start] = temp;
    }

    private int[] theArray;
}
```

Refer [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539653/java-defining-or-initializing-attributes-of-a-class) to learm more about Class attributes